# Bad Conformer Id Error when using rdkit function rdMolAlign.AlignMol()

Tags: python, bioinformatics, docking, rdkit

I was trying to run a docking simulation using rdkit library. But while running I am getting a value error stating: `ValueError: Bad Conformer Id`.

The `4POJ.pdb` file can be downloaded from the RCSB Protein data bank here: [4POJ](https://www.rcsb.org/structure/4poj)

Below is the code I am running, and in that line 8, `rdMolAlign.AlignMol` is the part I am getting this type of error.

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit.Chem import rdMolAlign

receptor= Chem.MolFromPDBFile('4POJ.pdb')
ligand= Chem.MolFromSmiles('CC(C(=O)O)N')

rdMolAlign.AlignMol(ligand,receptor)

ff=AllChem.MMFFGetMoleculeForceField(ligand,AllChem.MMFFGetMoleculeProperties(ligand),mmffvariant='MMFF94')

binding_energy= ff.Calcenergy()

print('binding energy:',binding_energy, 'kcal/mol')
```

Comment: Which RdKit version are you using?

Comment: im using 2022.09.1 version . Do i need to update?

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of things which were missing in your code. Before you AlignMol you need to get the conformer information of the ligands. This can be done with `Chem.AllChem.EmbedMultipleConfs`. And to calculate the binding energy you need to Setup the forcefield.

With those changes I am able to get the binding energy. Here is the modified code:

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem
from rdkit.Chem import rdMolAlign

receptor= Chem.MolFromPDBFile('4poj.pdb')
ligand = Chem.MolFromSmiles('CC(C(=O)O)N')
Chem.AllChem.EmbedMultipleConfs(ligand, numConfs=10)

rdMolAlign.AlignMol(ligand,receptor)

# Setup forcefield
mp = Chem.rdForceFieldHelpers.MMFFGetMoleculeProperties(ligand)
ff = Chem.rdForceFieldHelpers.MMFFGetMoleculeForceField(ligand, mp)

binding_energy= ff.CalcEnergy()
print('binding energy:',binding_energy, 'kcal/mol')
```

We get the output:

```
>> binding energy: 26.948799001339836 kcal/mol
```